# How can I write a generic anonymous method?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-function

Specifically, I want to write this:

```
public Func<IList<T>, T> SelectElement = list => list.First();
```

But I get a syntax error at `T`. Can't I have a generic anonymous method?

Comment: solved! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338867

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nope, sorry. That would require generic fields or generic properties, which are not features that C# supports. The best you can do is make a generic method that introduces T:

```
public Func<IList<T>, T> SelectionMethod<T>() { return list => list.First(); }
```

And now you can say:

```
Func<IList<int>, int> selectInts = SelectionMethod<int>();
```

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can, but `T` must be known:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public Func<IList<T>, T> SelectionMethod = list => list.First();
}
```

As an alternative you could use a generic method if you don't want to make the containing class generic:

```
public Func<IList<T>, T> SelectionMethod<T>()
{
    return list => list.First();
}
```

But still someone at compile time will need to know this `T`.

Comment: Yeah..that's the problem. I don't know what T is. It could be a char or a string.

Comment: Well then hopefully the consumer (the one that instantiates it) of the `Foo<T>` class will know it. If you never know it at compile time then generics is not the right artifact for you.

Comment: Well then your method or your class must take a generic parameter `T`.

Comment: The other problem is that I want the user to be able to override the selection method, which is why I had it as an anonymous function :) I know what `T` is when I call this method, but I use it in 2 different places (once on a List<char>, once on a List<string>), and I want to use the same method for both.

Comment: Well, then you could turn this `SelectionMethod` field into a virtual generic method so that the user would be able to override it. It's really a matter of method vs field here. Methods can be generic, fields can't. That's what the specification says. It's as simple as that. You can't fight against the specification or the type system.

Comment: By "override" I didn't mean in a subclass, I meant modify the property.

Comment: So if the user is supposed to modify this field (not property), why don't you provide him with a generic method which will take a  delegate: `public void DoSomething<T>(Func<IList<T>, T> foo) { ... }`. Now when the user calls this method he could pass as argument whatever expression he likes: `DoSomething(x => x.First());` and inside the method you're gonna do the job. You could even provide an overload of this method which will do the `.First()` stuff: `public void DoSomething<T>() { ... }` and you would construct an anonymous delegate inside.

Comment: @Darin: I wanted to specify it at the class level for re-usability... but this is the closest solution so far. Might have to do it that way.

Comment: @Darin: Actually, that won't work either...because like I said, T takes on two different values within the function.

Answer (score 1):

You declared only the return type as generic.

Try this:

```
public Func<IList<T>, T> SelectionMethod<T>() { return list => list.First(); }
```

The name of the thing you are declaring must include the type parameters for it to be a generic.  The compiler supports only generic classes, and generic methods.

So, for a generic class you must have

```
class MyGeneric<T> { 
   // You can use T here now
   public T MyField;
 }
```

Or, for methods

```
public T MyGenericMethod<T>( /* Parameters */ ) { return T; }
```

You can use T as the return parameter, only if it was declared in the method name first.

Even though it looks like the return type is declared before the actual method, the compiler doesn't read it that way.

Comment: Eh? No I didn't..even before the edit. And what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: That's a better explanation. I wanted a generic lambda though, which I guess doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void SomeContainerFunction()
    {
        const string NULL_VALUE = (string)null;

        Type GetValueType<T>(T value) => value?.GetType() ?? typeof(T);

        var typeOfNullValue = GetValueType(NULL_VALUE);

        Debug.WriteLine($"Value: {NULL_VALUE}, Type: {typeOfNullValue}");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When answering a question, please provide explanation associated with your code. Some people might not understand your code or don't see how it answers the question. See [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)